# How could I convert this henna tattoo to black and white?

Tags: gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to extract the henna tattoo pattern from the image and have tried applying a median filter (despeckle) and detecting the tattoo with Difference of Gaussians, but the detail I get is always way below what seems possible by looking at the image. I could also try tackling this problem with MathMap if I knew a good algorithm.
[image: Henna tattoo]

Comment: Using Gimp/python-fu is pointless if you cannot figure out a sequence of steps that use Gimp tools/filters with the adequate parameters. But for that you would use Gimp in interactive mode which is off-topic on SO. If you want to work at the pixel level, there are also image libraries for Python (pillow, etc.... )

Comment: Then would you suggest that I write another question where I post this image and the results of applying a median filter and difference of gaussians using pillow and ask how the results can be improved?

Comment: Yes, for instance